# How can I make a formula dynamically relating to a cell on "my" left in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Say I have two a table like this:

```
   Name    B    C    D
1  Joe     15  17  =B1-C1
2  Mike    25  22 (auto fill)
```

And I need to insert a column between C and D like this:

```
   Name    B    C    D      E
1  Joe     15  17   31    =C1-D1
2  Mike    25  22   34   (auto fill)
```

And I want the last column change to `C1-D1`. Every time I need to fill in myself. Is it possible to just say:

> My value = My 2nd left cell - My left cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`offset`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en), with the base point being the same cell in which you enter the formula. So, in D1 it would be

```
=offset(D1, 0, -2) - offset(D1, 0, -1)
```

When a new column is inserted between C and D, the above becomes

```
=offset(E1, 0, -2) - offset(E1, 0, -1)
```

which still has the meaning "My 2nd left cell - My left cell".